# Why can't I use my workspace if its a Git repo with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, maven, bitbucket

I have a git repo that has a lot of test scripts in it. I started by setting this repo as my "workspace" in eclipse so I could make changes directly with eclipse and then just push them up to bitbucket once they are done.

Eclipse wont let me do this, I cant see anything in my work space and when I try to import the local repo to the workspace it tells me  "Can't import project MavenTest from an existing workspace folder"

This doesn't make sense to me since I would have to make a separate workspace from my repo and then do the work into the workspace and manually copy it to the local repo and then push it up to bitbucket. Also pulling everything down will be a pain too since I'll have to copy any changes to my workspace. I defeats the whole purpose of version control.

Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong? I just want to work, push and pull all in the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse expects everything at the top level of its workspace directory to be a project, or otherwise content written by a plug-in through Eclipse's APIs. Any other content in the repository will be unusable and not importable as its location already overlaps the location of the workspace.

> I would have to make a separate workspace from my repo and then do the work into the workspace and manually copy it to the local repo and then push it up to bitbucket.

Wrong. You're under the misconception that everything shown in the workspace has to physically live under the workspace directory, which is very untrue. They don't have to be there, they don't even have to be physical files.

Typically you will make Eclipse aware of the local clone using its `Git Repositories` View, and then use the view's context menus to import content from the repository's working directory as projects in the workspace (or using a Maven wizard provided through M2E). **This import will not duplicate anything.** You will still have one canonical location for your sources: your repository.

https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Creating_Repositories

Comment: Great. That explains everything perfectly. Thanks nitind